# Not able to delete custom field created through Custom Fields app

Tags: abap, sap-fiori

I have created one custom field and enabled it for various UI and reports.

[image]

Now when I am trying to delete it after disabling everything it shows this error and doesn't delete the custom field:

> The selected fields cannot be deleted due to the following existing usages. Please remove the usages and try again.

> [image]

I have tried disabling everything and publishing it but still it gives the error.

Comment: Please don't use inadequate tags, first look at their tag info (e.g. custom-fields is reserved to Wordpress software, sap is ambiguous).